# Suppose a and b are two relatively prime numbers. Then what are the possible values of $\gcd (a + b,a ^2 + b ^2 )?$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose a and b are two relatively prime numbers. ie $\gcd(a , b) = 1.$ Then what are the possible values of $\gcd  (a + b,a^2 + b^2 ) ?$